# Six rebus puzzles - starting with three windows

Tags: rebus

Here are some rebus puzzles for you to solve:

1. Window Window Window TTTTTTTTT5
2. <sub>soft</sub>
3. li ne
4. lagond
5. Three age
6. teen teen teen teen

Comment: Have people gotten fed up of rebus puzzles and hence started downvoting them?

Comment: I still love them :D @TheDragonista

Comment: @TheDragonista - I think people like **good** rebus puzzles. Btw 40% of the 40 rebus puzzles in February have a net negative vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer displays the answer for all the rebus puzzles solved by @Gamow,@d'ala'cop and @Len:

Rebus 1:

> Windows + 9T + 5 = **Windows 95**

Rebus 2:

> soft in small font = **Microsoft**

Rebus 3:

> line with a break = **linebreak**

Rebus 4:

> go in land = **To go inland**

Rebus 5:

> Three can be written as tri = **Triage**

Rebus 6:

> 4 teen = **fourteen**

Answer (score 3):

Rebus 1:

> Windows + 9T + 5 = **Windows 95**

Rebus 3:

> line with a break = **linebreak**

Rebus 6:

> 4 teen = **fourteen**

Comment: You are correct so far...

Comment: Pistols at dawn?

Answer (score 3):

5. Three age

> **triage** (prioritization for medical treatment)

Comment: You got it right!

Comment: Comments left on this answer by myself and @d'alar'cop were mysteriously deleted...

Answer (score 2):

Rebus 2:

> Microsoft

Rebus 4:

> To go inland

Rebus 5:

> Triple H (a wrestler... probably wrong)

Comment: Sorry, but "Triple H" is wrong. Try again.

Comment: +1; you're still ahead of Gamow at least for the moment!

Comment: @rand yep, only one or two days left now :p